# Knockout sorting with bootstrap div structure not working

Tags: css, sorting, knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

Working with bootstrap 3 and trying to enable sorting in bootstrap grid. I have an observable knockout collection. I'm trying to use this jsfiddle which is a simple example.

http://jsfiddle.net/brendonparker/6S85t/

It works for me with the table structure but can't make it work with the below div structure. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Name
            Type
            Sector

```
<div id="workqueue" class="container-fluid grid-col-wrap" data-bind="foreach: myCollection">
    <div class="row equal" >
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 grid-data" data-bind="text: Name"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 grid-data" data-bind="text: Type"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-1 hidden-xs grid-data" data-bind="text: Sector">     </div>
    </div>
```

"

Comment: The problem is with the css of the div structure?  Or is it that you can't get the model-data to bind correctly to the divs in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I can't really figure out what the problem is.  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6S85t/111/)'s a JSFiddle example that (I believe) works totally fine.

All I changed from your original div structure was your example collection--`myCollection`.  I changed it to use the `Records` collection you already had.  And then from your fiddle, I changed the `<thead>` to be a div structure as well.  I also added css `width` properties to make it all look more like a table.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks - the issue was with KO model binding. I had two different VeiwModels on the same MVC view. The header was outside the scope of model binding ko.applyBindings(DisplayPlanVM, $("#workqueue")[0]);

Comment: Your post made me realize there is nothing to blame bootstrap for.